# Paypal how to differentiate between multiple subscriptions for a same user

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

I'm currently programming a small basket app and I was wondering what was the variable that would be used to differentiate between subcriptions for one user.

Let say my user has 4 subscriptions, and it is now the time to receive its recurring payment.  I receive the payment message from Paypal, parse it and do my DB update.  How do I know which recurring I need to process?

From what I read, its probably the subscr_id=I-HPDM8GP... that I need to check but I'm not sure?

Thanks

Comment: The ID of a subcription is, err. the subscription ID. Nothing mysterious here.

Comment: This definition is coming from Paypal site:

subscr_id : ID generated by PayPal for the subscriber. 
Length: 19 characters

So is it the id of the client or subscription???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty broad question so I'm going to have to make a couple of assumptions...

1)  You're using standard subscription buttons..??
2)  You have a users table in your database already, and it relates to an orders/invoices table in your database by customer ID..??

If those assumptions are accurate, then what I would recommend is that you include the order ID from your system in the "invoice" parameter with the subscription button code.

If you're not already using it then it would be wise to setup an IPN solution to process subscription payments, and within the IPN data you would get the same order ID back in that "invoice" parameter, so within that solution you could update your system accordingly using that order ID which then relates back to your customer IDs in your own system.

With all of this data included and related correctly in your system you could easily pull reports for different users that include all of their subscriptions and payment history.

Comment: Since Paypal is sending an invoice, we decided not to produce any.

Comment: In my system, when the transaction is completed and validated, we create the client environment.  The problem with recurring payment is that, since I don't know how to differentiate between a new subscription and a recurring one, I keep creating client environments...  This is why I was trying to understand, if the "subscr_id" was the parameter to compare with my DB to know if it was a new subscription or a recurring payment on an old subscription...

Comment: I guess you could hit your DB and search for a profile with that ID already, and if you can't find it, then assume it's new.  I would question your whole setup, though, really.  No reason not to have your own invoice table.

Comment: In fact, I have created a "transaction" table to record all transaction. I guess it can also be called invoice table...  I'm going to verify this table for every subscr_id coming in from Payapal.  If it can't be found, then its a new subscription and I will than create a client environment.  Thanks for your support.

Comment: Just keep in mind that in most systems an order/invoice could have multiple transactions associated with it, so usually you would still have an orders table, a customers table, and a transactions table like you mention.  Of course, whatever works best for you, though.